# What name of the property to change the color of the field informed in the screen shot?

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I'm creating my personal vscode theme, but I didn't think the name property to leave the same color of my theme. Below the print indicating the field:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```json
"editorGroupHeader.tabsBackground"
```